# java, StandardCharsets utf-16 issue

Tags: java, encoding, utf-16

I'm trying to understand why the results are different when I try to write a test string using different encodings.

For `StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE`, the result is `"test"` (seems correct), while for `StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE` the result is `" t e s t"` (seems wrong).

Can someone please explain why in the case of `UTF_16BE` the result is having unnecessary spaces between letters?

```java
String filename="C:\\Users\\name\\Downloads\\debugging.txt";
String str="test";

File fl = new File(filename);

try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fl);

    //BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE)); //seems does work
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE)); //seems does not work

    bw.write(str);
} catch (IOException ignored) {
    //some actions
}
```

Comment: standard window's notepad does support utf-16 LE and BE

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the java code. What's wrong is the tool you use to read debugging.txt. text files do not  contain the encoding used to write them, hence, to open a text file, you need to supply __2__ things: A file, AND an encoding. Do it right (pass 'UTF-16BE') and it would look normal. Your editor is guessing at the encoding, and guesses ISO-8559-1, which would result in something that _looks_ like ' t e s t'.

Comment: yes, thank you for the reply! the BOM is missing, so this seems to be the cause

Comment: @newman The BOM is intentionally not added; use `UTF-16` (no LE or BE) and it -is- added if I recall correctly. The spec is explicit about this. If you want the BOM anyway, add it by hand - send `'\uFEFF'` before sending the string. Editors are not guaranteed to guess correctly when the BOM is there, but it improves the odds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#standard) says:

> When decoding, the UTF-16BE and UTF-16LE charsets interpret the
> initial byte-order marks as a ZERO-WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE; when
> encoding, they do not write byte-order marks.

Without a [BOM](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark), editors have to guess the correct encoding and they could be not so clever.  Some editor could simply not support some encoding.  So it depends on the editor that you use to read the file.

Comment: thank you! yes, indeed, the BOM is missing (I have opened the result as binary). Strange, I thought that JAVA writes BOM automatically.

Comment: The same Javadoc says that `UTF-16` writes the BOM but you cannot choose between  big-endian and little-endian.